# Can these signal traces cause EMI and crosstalk issues?

Tags: emc, signal-integrity

I have a GND and also a power "plane" pouring on my PCB's top layer.

My signal *have to* cross between these pourings (around the dotted circle):

[image]

Is this considered as a bad practice, and shall I avoid this by changing these signals to the bottom layer before exiting from the GND pour?

Due to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdEHJXs5xpw, it's very not recommended to route signals out from solid pourings, but they only talked about having two pours both GND. I wish to know if having GND and 3.3V pour makes any difference or it's still advised to change layers and escape from this EMI trap.

Although this can be a different question but this below one is very tightly coupled to this earlier:

Shall I avoid "neighbouring" a signal trace with both 3.3V and GND pouring? Is this causing problems? Shall I route these tracks/pour differently?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if it's accurate to say that "it's very not recommended to route signals out from solid pourings." My understanding is that any time you have a trace carrying a high-frequency signal, you should have a return path right next to it. That means that having an _unbroken_ plane next to your signal trace is _helpful_, but I don't think it means that having a _broken_ plane next to your signal trace is _harmful_.

Comment: You need to tell us what the edge rates of those signals are.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what the parasitics are between those traces and the planes, there are only a few pfs of capacitance between the planes. So you might get coupling in between the traces and the planes but it will be minimal, unless the traces are carrying gigahertz signals.

It really depends on what kind of speed those traces carry if it's above 10 MHz you will have issues cause you don't have a ground near the traces, so your rise times could suffer. If it's below roughly 10 megahertz then it probably doesn't matter.

Generally you want to continuous ground under traces and near them on the connector to reduce inductance on return currents through the ground.

One thing you should also not do is cross power planes with fast signals without bypass caps. If you need to achieve fast rise times then add up/estimate the parasitic resistance and inductance on the ground plane and do a spice simulation of the digital ports with trace and grind plane parasitics.